# How to trigger ASP.NET Core API function when the parameter is included in URL

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, postman, httprequest

I try to trigger a specific method (the second one) in `HeroesController` class:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Hero> Get()
    {
        return Heroes;
    }

    [HttpGet("/name={term}")]
    public IEnumerable<Hero> Get(string term)
    {
        return Heroes;
    }
```

After calling this URL:

```
https://localhost:44375/heroes/?name=Spider
```

The first method is triggered, not the second. Why is that so? How to trigger the second one which receives term parameter?

Comment: because the route is not matched, you need to use the url `https://localhost:44375/heroes/name=Spider` - but using the `=` in the pattern is unusual.

Comment: Yes, but I need to create a method that knows how to respond to this specific URL: https://localhost:44375/heroes/?name=Spider

Comment: so you already have the firsrt `Get` method (as you said, it's invoked). The url you want has a part called `query string`. The `Get` method then should be like `Get(string name)`. The second `Get` makes no sense, just remove the `[HttpGet("/name={term}")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by King King, the url is not matched, but the best way to do this is;

```
[HttpGet] 
public IEnumerable<Hero> Get([FromQuery] string term) 
{ 
    return Heroes; 
}
```

Then the endpoint would be hit if a query parameter, `term` is passed `https://localhost:44375/heroes?term=Spider`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to distinguish here - URL parameters versus query parameters. If you want to supply variable while doing you GET HTTP call these are the options:

1. Variable you want to pass can be part of the URL:

   http://localhost:8080/yourResourceName/{varValue}

   ```
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<IActionResult> Get(string varValue)
    {

    }
   ```
2. Variable you want to pass can be a query parameter:

   http://localhost:8080/yourResourceName?varname={varValue}

   ```
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]string varValue)
    {

    }
   ```